# Mixing aggregate and non-aggregate values in a subquery, standard or Oracle feature?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, standards

When I run this in Oracle 10g I get the error "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" as I would expect:

```
WITH a as (select  1 somenumber  from dual),
     b as (           select 'foo' foo from dual 
            union all select 'goo'     from dual)
SELECT (select 0.5 from b) 
FROM a
```

However when I run the following statement I don't get an error and instead I get a return of '2.5'.

```
WITH a as (select  1 somenumber  from dual),
     b as (           select 'foo' foo from dual 
            union all select 'goo'     from dual)
SELECT (select sum(a.somenumber)  + 0.5 from b) 
FROM a
```

Is this standard to sum over the subquery and then add the 0.5 as though it was done after running the subquery? Or is this some Oracle feature/bug?

**Edit**: For those curious the actual code looked more like this:

```
WITH a as (select  1 somenumber  from dual),
     b as (           select 'foo' foo from dual 
            union all select 'goo'     from dual)
SELECT (select sum(a.somenumber)  + customfunction(a.somenumber) from b) 
FROM a
```

Comment: This is SQL feature actually :) You will get exactly the same result on any SQL database.

Comment: as kambajin said: a feture otherwise it is a bug. dont relly on this!

Comment: @Linger: Like I said I expected it to return an error

Comment: @Kombajn: Thanks! I didn't know you were allowed to add a constant when doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:  it is standard.  Your query is:

```
SELECT (select sum(a.somenumber)  + 0.5
        from b
       )  as sum_from_b
FROM a
```

For each row in `b`, it is adding up `a.somenumber` and then adding 0.5.  You are allowed to add a constant to a calculated expression.  This is standard SQL.

Note that what you are really doing is:

```
SELECT a.somenumber * (select count(*) from b) + 0.5
FROM a;
```

There is no reason to have a correlated subquery in this case.

Comment: select 'constant' from B - giving 2 rows - and no error. you are right - I think

Comment: Thanks! This is a vast simplification of a very long report I've been debugging for most the afternoon. But there's a piece of logic which relies on how I've stated it above.